# APK marca Admitidos por esta aplicación: 0 en Google Play Developer Console

Tags: android-studio, google-play

Acabo de publicar mi primer Aplicación en la play store, pero me indica que ningún dispositivo es compatible con mi APK.

He estado leyendo y la documentación indica que el problema está en el archivo Manifest.xml. Ya he realizado modificaciones pero sigue sin aceptarme dispositivos. Anexo el contenido del archivo Manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_caserito"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".presentation.activities.SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".presentation.activities.LoginActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".presentation.activities.RegisterActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Navigator" />
    <activity android:name=".presentation.activities.ForgotPasswordActivity" />

    <receiver
        android:name=".util.Notification.AlarmReceiver"
        android:enabled="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name=".util.Notification.AlarmReceiver2"
        android:enabled="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!-- Permisos para la camara y almacenamiento de la galeria -->
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.com.vansuita.pickimage.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        tools:replace="android:authorities">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/picker_provider_paths" />
    </provider>

    <activity android:name=".presentation.activities.ImageDetailActvity"></activity>
</application>
```

También este es el contenido del archivo build.gradle: apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.apuitiza.caserito"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '27.1.1'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-dynamic-animation:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

//Librerias para el consumo del webServices
implementation group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
//Librerias para mostrar el grafico
implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.3.0'
implementation 'com.txusballesteros:FitChart:1.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'

implementation 'com.github.ybq:AndroidSpinKit:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:9.0.0-rc1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:9.0.0-rc1'
//Librerias de imagenes
implementation 'com.github.jrvansuita:PickImage:2.2.4'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

implementation 'com.tbuonomo.andrui:viewpagerdotsindicator:2.1.2'
implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.3'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
```

}

Comment: ¿y probaste con estas modificaciones?

Comment: Qué tal @Anthony_Puitiza, de casualidad ¿cuál es la versión que escogiste para desarrollar tu aplicación?

Comment: Acuérdate que hay dispositivos android como el oreo que lo posee muy poca gente, se me viene a la cabeza de que desarrollaste la aplicación para la versión más reciente. Y cuando es así, solo el celular que tenga esa versión de android podrá usar tu aplicación, en cambio otra versión pasada como "Ice Cream Sandwich", etc mo podrá usarla.

Comment: https://www.mejorprogramacion.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/versiones-android.png, aquí un ejemplo de lo que te redacte. Si ves los porcentajes, significa que hay muy poca gente que posee esos celulares con esa versión de android. En resumen, muy pocas personas podrán usar tu aplicación.

Comment: La aplicación esta definida para soportar como minimo API19 @GianFrancoAlexisPomaVidal

Answer (score 1):

hay varias razones por las que puede filtrar la aplicación, como ejemplo, que tu aplicación define el uso de la cámara y solo dispositivos con cámara podrán instalarla, por lo tanto te sugiero agregar:

```
<uses-feature  android:name="android.hardware.camera"   android:required="false"/>
```

para indicar que dispositivos que no cuenten con cámara puedan instalar tu aplicación.

---

De cualquier forma **si Google Play indica 0 dispositivos soportados la causa es otra y esta generalmente es que alguna dependencia esta haciendo uso de alguna librería obsoleta**.

Como ejemplo las librerías apache

[**Eliminación del cliente HTTP de Apache**](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes#behavior-apache-http-client)

ejemplo:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
    ...
}
```

Aquí hay un aso en el sitio en inglés:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308560/supported-android-devices-0-devices

Revisa cual de las dependencias usadas en tu proyecto hacen uso de las clases Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Me paso algo parecido, básicamente lo que hice fue ir actualizando mis dependencias una por una revisando que no impactara mi funcionalidad y con eso.

También encontré en otro lado que era importante usar la version mas nueva de android en compileSdkVersion y targetSdkVersion, esto no afecta al contrario beneficia la compatibilidad de tu aplicación.

Para ir probando en la consola de Google puedes ponerlo en Registro Previo.

[image: Cuando realice las correcciones se vio como subieron los dispositivos de cero a 18,542]